# Summary Task in Task List - Display Name

Tags: content-type, splistitem, task-list

Hello

I have a Task List, and I want to add items to it programaticaly in C#. I have a problem with adding a summary task. Now I figured out how to add such item:

```
 var myList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyList"];
    SPContentType type = myList.ContentTypes["Summary Task"];
    SPListItem newItem= myList.Folders.Add();
    newItem["ContentTypeId"] = type.Id;
    newItem.Update();
    newItem["Title"] = "MyTitle";
    newItem.Update();
    myList.Update();
```

The problem is, Title column contains something like "79_.000" (the number increments for newly added element, guess its the id) instead of "MyTitle". When I skip the newItem["ContentTypeId"] = type.Id; line (and update) tthe name is ok, but the item is not recognized as a summary task. I see that the DisplayName property is the wrong one, but Name is ok. Unfortunately DisplayName is read only, so I can't modify it (but maybe this would not be the best approach)

I'm using SP 2010 foundation. Any help would be apprectated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT*

Just checked it out on my environment, and you need to create the item as a folder. Summary Tasks is a folder within a task list.

The code for this is the following:

```
var myList = web.Lists["Tasks"];
SPContentType type = myList.ContentTypes["Summary Task"];
// URL to your task list, Item type (Folder), Folder name (Your title)
SPListItem newItem = myList.Items.Add("/Lists/Tasks", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, "MyTitle");
newItem["ContentTypeId"] = type.Id;
// Change description
newItem["Body"] = "Description";
newItem.Update();
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work. I also see, that if i try to fill any other field after the first Update(), the value is not changed, so maybe the problem is with the steps i do to create this item. I used this article [link](http://suguk.org/blogs/tomp/archive/2006/09/28/Adding_SPListItems.aspx) but since its for 2007, maybe something is out of date

Comment: ok, a litte disclaimer to teh comment above: I can modify the 'default' fields, like Description, but I have also added 2 extra fields (currency) and i can't modify those. Still, Name column is not being modyfied (but the Name property has the good value while debugging)

Comment: this works indeed, I have not tried the overloaded Add() and it looks like I should have had.. thanks a lot!